# Is drinking carbs+protein during workout equivalent to eating the same amounts?

Tags: muscle, bodybuilding, nutrition, muscle-mass, muscle-gain

In a good old [writeup on Advanced Workout Nutrition](http://web.archive.org/web/20120204031453/http://www.johnberardi.com/articles/nutrition/advanced_workout_nutrition.htm), John Berardi recommends drinking 30g of carbs and 15g of protein per hour of training.

How would eating the same amounts of solid food compare, say a small banana (~20g carbs, 1g protein) + 1oz edamame (12g protein, 12g carbs)? Tho goal is maximum muscle synthesis.

Comment: I think that would depend on several factors including the rate and efficiency of absorption.

Comment: Chewing is an important part of your digestive process. There are plenty of resources on that if you'd just search chewing & digestion. I wouldn't leave out chewing food for simply drinking. It'll work, but you'll also be missing out.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically it should not matter too much. The problem is that eating, for instance, fruit instead of drinking a protein shake can lead to different reactions from your body. I've been told by my trainer that cultivated food, whether it be fruit, meat or other things, will have less nutrition than the registered foods, since they can be grown on different soils or water cultures or what other. The other aspect is that when for instance eating meat, your body needs to digest the meat, which takes longer and your body will get the needed protein later. Drinking protein supplements will in most cases result in faster body intake, since you don't need to digest the whole cow before you get to the protein. The same is for the banana and the needed sugars.

Again, this is what I learn from my trainer. You eat your regular foods with the necessary carbs and protein. Your use the supplements before or after the training to enhance, protect or repair your muscles. It is therefore a combination of the two that is best for the training.

Comment: What is "registered food"?

Comment: Well, it might be bad English, but here is what I mean. An orange is said to have a specific amount of vitamin C. This is registered. however, the actual orange you buy in a super market might come from a water culture and contains much less vitamin C as is registered. so, you think you eat an orange and take a certain amount of vitamin c, but in fact you only get 10% of it. This also applies to chicken from bio industry and a bio chicken, etc. etc.

Comment: Ok.  I understand now.